# Lifetimes when adding temporary values to vectors

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having some problems trying to understand how Rust lifetimes works in some situations, like below. I can't get it working but I'm not sure why.

```
struct Bar {
    value: &'static str,
}

struct Foo<'a, T: 'a> {
    bar: &'a T,
}

fn main() {
    let mut foos = Vec::new();

    let y = Bar {
        value: "Hello, world!",
    };
    let x = Foo { bar: &y };

    foos.push(x);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `y` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:15:25
   |
15 |     let x = Foo { bar: &y };
   |                         ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
18 | }
   | - `y` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created
```

This is a simplified example of what I'm actually trying to achieve:

```
fn main() {
    let foos = vec![
        Foo { bar: &(Bar { value: "a" }) },
        Foo { bar: &(Bar { value: "b" }) },
    ];
}
```

I'd appreciate any ideas, thoughts or explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## After Non-Lexical Lifetimes

Both versions of your code now work, thanks to [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423).

## Before Non-Lexical Lifetimes

Your problem can be simplified to this example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foos = Vec::new();
    let y = &42;
    foos.push(y);
}
```

The important thing to remember in this case is that variables are destroyed in the inverse order they are created. You could almost look at the code as

```
fn main() {
    let mut foos = Vec::new();
    {
        let y = &42;
        {
            foos.push(y);
        }
        // destroy y
    }}
    // destroy foos
}
```

For simple values like I am showing, this doesn't really matter, but it's more important when you have complicated types that have custom `Drop` implementations.

A simple fix is to reorder the statements:

```
fn main() {
    let y = &42;
    let mut foos = Vec::new();
    foos.push(y);
}
```

Now, it's guaranteed that the thing being referred to *lives longer* than the reference stored in the vector. For your original reduced example, this works:

```
let y = Bar { value: "Hello, world!" };
let x = Foo { bar: &y };
let mut foos = Vec::new();
foos.push(x);
```

Your original code has a bit trickier problem. Let's look at the expansion of the `vec!` macro:

```
let foos = <[_]>::into_vec(Box::new([Foo { bar: &(Bar { value: "a" }) }]));
```

Which we can simplify down to

```
let foos = Box::new(&42);
```

The problem is that the temporary variable is, well, *temporary*. It only exists for the duration of the function call. This means that the reference to the temporary variable can't last longer than that. That's why the error message suggests *"consider using a `let` binding to increase its lifetime"*. By doing so, the variable will live longer than the function call.

> Is it possible to make the temporary value last longer without using a let statement? The vector will have many values, say 30. So I'll have to place 30 let statements?

No, you have to be explicit about how long they *should* live, so you need to be explicit about where they are. I see two solutions:

1. Change your structures so that they own items, instead of referring to them:

   ```
   struct Foo<T> {
       bar: T,
   }

   let foos = vec![
       Foo { bar: Bar { value: "a" } },
       Foo { bar: Bar { value: "b" } },
   ];
   ```
2. Create a vector that owns all the inner types, then map over it to get references:

   ```
   let bars = vec![Bar { value: "a" }, Bar { value: "b" }];
   let foos: Vec<_> = bars.iter().map(|bar| Foo { bar: bar }).collect();
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to make the temporary value last longer without using a let statement? The vector will have many values, say 30. So I'll have to place 30 let statements? Any ideas?

Comment: Just another question: is it possible to return `foos` from a function? For example: let foos2: Vec<_> = foos(). I tried something like "fn foos<T>() -> Vec<Foo<T>> { }" but it says there's a type mismatch.

Comment: @caio It depends on which variant you have. The owned version should be fine, the second one (with the map) is not. That one has references to items that won't live beyond the function call. For more detail, I'd recommend asking another top-level question!

Comment: did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581855/how-to-return-a-vector-containing-generic-values